# how can i add/ pass textbox value in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

```
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title>Directives</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
            angular.module('exampleApp', [])
            .controller('defaultCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function ($scope, $http) { 
              $scope.search = search;
              var url = 'http://data.bioontology.org/search?q='+search+'&ontologies=RADLEX&include_properties=false&include_views=false&includeObsolete=false&require_definition=false&exact_match=false&categories';
              // i want to pass the entered text value into this url

                        $scope.testGET = function () {
                        $http({
                                method: 'GET',// get method
                                url: url, // the url goes here
                            headers: { 
                                    'Authorization': 'apikey token=076d0636-694a-47df-bf0d-ccf2489853b4' // Authorization key 
        },
                            }).success(function (data) {
                                  $scope.testGET = data.collection;
                         });
                        }
                    }
                ]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
<div class="panel panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="text" class="col-md-12" ng-model="search">
        <button ng-click="testGET()">Test GET</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in testGET">
          {{todo.prefLabel}}
          {{todo.definition}}
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the testGET method is where you would read the value of the search variable.

Initially you should just set it to an empty string.

```
$scope.search = ''; // not $scope.search = search
```

Then:

```
$scope.testGET = function () {
    var url = 'http://data.bioontology.org/search?q=' + $scope.search + '&ontologies=RADLEX&include_properties=false&include_views=false&includeObsolete=false&require_definition=false&exact_match=false&categories';
   // .. the http call.
};
```

Oh.. and in the success method by doing:

```
$scope.testGET = data.collection;
```

You're essentially overriding your method. That's probably not you meant.

Here's a plunkr with it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wCEC5Z2eOpQ99ouVi5ts?p=preview

Comment: hi your example works but if i try to change the value its not working

Comment: as I said, in your success callback you're overriding the method :). Remove the code in the callback (or at least the assignment) and it should work a second time.

Comment: kindly can you help me with it.. i dont know how to do that

Comment: how can i remove the braces in 'definition' json data.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: in the plunker example iam binding 2 data's prefLabel  and definition, but in definition iam getting braces ..how can i remove the braces and show the value

Comment: The description field is an array. I updated  the plunkr with an example of how you could handle that. You'll probably have to process the result a bit in the code before displaying it. Ask another question if you don't know how to do that - it's outside the scope of this one. (don't take this the wrong way but you should probably read up on javascript as a whole some more.)